# WPF: TextBox.Text not updated when source is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have the following **TextBox** defined in my XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="LicenseKey" 
         Style="{StaticResource LicenseKeyInvalidStyle}" 
         Width="150"
         Text="{Binding LicenseKey, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsReadOnly="False" />
```

In my ViewModel I have the following property that the **TextBox** binds to:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The License key for this product
    /// </summary>
    public string LicenseKey
    {
        get { return _LicenseKey; }
        set
        {
            if (_LicenseKey != value)
            {
                _LicenseKey = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.LicenseKey);
            }
        }
    }
    private String _LicenseKey;
```

I provide a "Paste License Key" **Button** that will paste whatever is on the clipboard to the LicenseKey property.

```
    public void PasteLicenseKeyButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            LicenseKey = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
        }
    }
```

If I type or use CTRL+V on the **TextBox** to change the Text value, the property is correctly updated and the change is shown in the **TextBox**.  If I use the "Paste License Key" **Button**, the `LicenseKey` property is updated but the new value of is not modified in the TextBox field.

How can I get the TextBox.Text value to update when the 'LicenseKey' is updated via the view model?

Comment: Does your `ViewModel` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Do you set your view's `DataContext` to your `ViewModel` instance?

Comment: I realized that the issue was due to using SimpleMvvm and not setting the property on the correct view model.  SimpleMvvm provides for cahnge tracking via the ViewModelDetailBase and creates a copy of the view model to do this.  Funny how I always do my best debugging shortly after posting on SO!!

Comment: Download snoopwpf.codeplex.com. It is an awesome tool for discovering the cause of these kinds of bugs. You could drill down to the DataContext of the TextBox and it would've helped you realize that you were  bound to a different instance of the ViewModel when it's property didn't change.